Can't log into 24.04 and 22.04 won't boot since post installation bug blasted graphics interface
I have two SSDs. 22.04, 23.10 & Windows are installed on one and I just installed 24.04 on the other. I first created a new partition by shrinking the /home partition and creating the new partition in the now unused space.
I downloaded Gnome-Tweaks to 24.04 and when I changed the pointer, the graphics display blew up and was replaced with a white screen with a picture of a sad face on a computer and:
"Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover.
Please log out and try again."
No mouse pointer is present, only a button that says Log Out, which when pressed takes me back to the login screen.
I reinstalled 24.04 from a Live USB as before. The grub menu is the same as it was, but nothing changed when I logged into 24.04, same white screen. Then I rebooted and selected 22.04, but this now never even gets to the login screen. Instead I get five lines of error text followed by: "You are in emergency mode." I can do nothing from this point.
I can boot fine to Windows and also 23.10, which I'm using to write this. My files are in another partition and seem fine.
Help! Is there a way I can recover my system? Thanks.

I realised my 22.04 boot issue was that a partition got reformatted during 24.04 installation and the UUID was changed. I had to edit the 22.04 /etc/fstab file to replace the old UUID with the new so that 22.04 would boot. Once I was back in 22.04, I restored my .config dir and logged back in to find that the change to the RedGlass pointer was working. So I ran gnome-tweaks and changed it back to Yaru, rebooted to 24.04 and all is fine.
The gnome-tweaks bug has been confirmed, which is also good news.
THanks.

24.04 is still a very new version. You should wait at least for 24.04.1 until you upgrade. Many people are facing problem right now with this new version.
Report your bugs and give the developers a few weeks to react.

Thanks, I didn't upgrade an existing distribution, but installed the new 24.04 to try it out. I've never had an issue doing so back to about 2010, so really wasn't expecting catastrophic failure. I guess someone has to find the bugs and have filed a report on this one.

Update. I deleted (renamed) the .config dir from my home dir and now can log into 24.04. I still cannot successfully boot to 22.04 though. Recovery mode works partially, but fsck fails on a particular partition. However what I believe is the same partition can be successfully accessed from 24.04.

There is a method to recover Linux OS from such crashes like this white screen with this message.
"Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred, and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again."
I just used this method on my crash of Ubuntu 24.04.
When there is this white screen or whenever Linux hangs during start-up or during running, then You can press these key combinations
Ctrl + Alt + F3
Ctrl + Alt + F1
These key combinations bring tty CLI console in which You can login as Your user and then type any commands
Like as You mentioned, You can run this command
sudo rm -rf ~/.config
or similar command to reset gnome settings to factory defaults
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/dbus/user
sudo rm -rf ~/.gnome ~/.gnome2 ~/.gconf ~/.gconfd ~/.metacity
Or You can run these exact commands to change mouse cursor like mentioned in this bug report that currently, probably only these 2 mouse cursors are working correctly now in Linux Ubuntu 24.04.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/2062377
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'Yaru'
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'Adwaita'
Then You can restart gdm service (Gnome Display Manager) to be able to log again into Linux OS out of tty console without the need of restarting the computer
sudo service gdm restart
As a side note, in similar crashes, You can install lightdm (Light Display Manager) and stop gdm and switch to lightdm if gdm is causing problems, especially when start-up of Linux OS hangs because of gdm.
Ctrl + Alt + F3
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo service gdm stop
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
select lightdm instead of gdm
sudo service lightdm restart

Thanks, these tips look very useful.
